# App consisting of back issues of magazine

Tags: app-store

I'm making an app that is for presenting the old versions of a magazine (i have the necessary permissions). Right now, each magazine is sold in the stores, but the older versions, like 2005, are not on the street anymore.

I want to make an app that simply has 12 buttons, one for each magazine edition in a full year, and sell this app as the editions of my magazine for the specific year (i.e., an app for 2005, another for 2006 and so on. The PDFs would be stored locally in each app, thus not requiring internet connection. Also, the pdf reader i already have implemented, with favorites, transactions and stuff..

I couldn't present this magazine in a browser for example, because I don't want the users to download the magazines and share them -- they are supposed to be only for someone who buys the app.

Would Apple reject my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I think would be the best for you to organize your applications is to provide a viewer application, and then implement micro transactions that allow for the purchase of the previous versions of your families magazine.

I can imagine a view in a few different ways but simply downloading a magazine into a webview would be the simplest that I can think of at the moment. I'm not sure how a user would share it because even if you included it in an image/pdf format you can disable user interaction, even screen shotting I'd imagine, keeping them from removing it from your app(As far as I know how).

To directly answer your question, no, I don't think Apple would reject your application, though depending on how the built in bookstore works, it may be easier for you to simply try to publish it to that through iTunes, or whatever that process is, and save yourself the code.

Comment: Going to keep my answer the same, I don't think you'll have a problem with Apple rejecting your app. I would emphasize however that you need to make sure to disable all kinds of user interaction such as copy/pasting, screenshots, etc, if you are that worried about users sharing your content.

Comment: Ok, but see that i wouldn't need to use a webView to present the pdfs, neither download any of them.. i have a license purchased of a pdf reader and i would like to use it to show the pdfs. Another thing is, i would make an app for each year..

Comment: Yes, of course, the web viewer alternative was merely a suggestion. Your current method using a pdf viewer with preloaded pdfs should be fine. I would discourage you from making an app for each year, especially if you have 12 different years you'd like to go back on. Its much more elegant to take that little bit of extra time to implement transactions in your app then to spend time duplicating and publishing your application 12 separate times. Imagine if a future update of iOS somehow breaks how you're doing something in your application, itd be a nightmare to fix.